# Java : Dependency Injection by introspection, recursion and annotation

Tags: java

So the idea behind this is that I have a main class that is starting a Server (servlet) and I want to inject all the classes that servlet will need in the future so it doesn't instantiate them himself (considered bad practice ?)

I create an annotation `ToInject` to indicate the attributes within classes that will need to be injected for the whole system to work.

I call my `injectionService` right before I instantiate the servlet : `InjectionService.injectObject(ServletMain.class)` and my hope is that with the recursion it will instantiate and place the right objects at the right places.
I'm using a `HashMap` to keep the instances of each type of object I iterate over.

In my `ServletMain` class : instead of writing `LoginController log = new LoginController();` I would write `@ToInject LoginController log;` .

Is this the right way to go ? It doesn't work right now but I can't see what I'm missing.

Edit/PS : the reason why I'm not using Spring-like tools is because the assignment doesn't allow us to use those.

I realize this is a very specific question, thank you in advance for the answers.

```
    package utils;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import domain.factory.IFactory;

public class InjectionService {

  private static IFactory factory = null;
  private static HashMap<Object, Object> map_class_instance = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

  public static void injectObject(Object o) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException,
      ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
      IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    Field[] fields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
      if (f.isAnnotationPresent(ToInject.class)) {
        if (map_class_instance.get(o) == null) {
          Constructor cons = (Constructor) Class.forName((String) o).getDeclaredConstructor();
          cons.setAccessible(true);
          Object obj = cons.newInstance();
          map_class_instance.put(o.getClass(), obj);
          // recursif
          f.set(o, map_class_instance.get(f));
          injectObject(f);

        }
        f.set(o, map_class_instance.get(f));
        injectObject(f);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the question? If you just want someone to review your code you need to post on the code review site.

Comment: "I realize this is a very specific question" => What question?

Comment: If the question is "Is this the right way to go ?", the answer is no. CDI, SPring, and other frameworks already provide dependency injection. Don't reinvent the wheel.